# Variance of a summation

Tags: probability

Consider $X_1, ..., X_n,...$ independent variables that satisfy:
$E[X_i]=1+\frac{1}{1+i^2}$ and $Var[X_i]=\sqrt{i}$, $i=1,2,...$.

Determine the variance of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i}{i^{1/4}}$.

I have:
Because of independence, $Var[\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i}{i^{1/4}}]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Var[\frac{X_i}{i^{1/4}}]$. This is where I am stuck. Can I say that the variance is:
$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^{1/4}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^{1/4}=0$?

Comment: Are you trying to find the variance of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i i^{-\frac14}$ or the limit of that as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: I made a mistake there by misinterpreting the question in the book. I think the variance of that sum should be $n$.

Comment: That is correct (using the hint from @Samrat Mukhopadhyay's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For any random variable $X$, and constant $a$, $$Var(aX)=a^2Var(X)$$

Comment: Thanks! Stupid of me to forgot that. So in that case I assume that the variance is: $Var[\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i}{i^{1/4}}]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Var[\frac{X_i}{i^{1/4}}]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}Var[X_i]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\sqrt{i}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 1=n$

Comment: That's correct @Holograph.